# Нарушение доступа для чтения, C

Tags: c, память, структуры

Изучаю работу со структурами, динамическим выделением памяти на си, застрял на одной задаче:

> В файле содержится следующая информация о железнодорожном
>   расписании:номер поезда, время прибытия на станцию, время отправления,
>   название станции. Разработать структуру Поезд, соответствующую формату
>   файла. Создать массив структур.

Мой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define dim 256
#define ldim 32
//--------------------------------Base functions--------------------------------
int Power10(int x) {
    //10^x
    int result = 1;
    while (x > 0) {
        result = result * 10;
        x = x - 1;
    }
    return result;
}
int StrToInt(char *p) {
    //Transforming string to integer
    int i = 0, length = sizeof(p)-1, result = 0;
    while ((p[i] >= '0') && (p[i] <= '9')) {
        result = result + (int(p[i]) - 48) *Power10(length - i - 1);
            i++;
    }
    return result;
}
int GetInt(char *p,int *i) {
    //Getting integer from the string
    char *p_GIBuf = NULL;
    int Bi = 0;
    p_GIBuf = (char*)malloc(ldim);
    while ((p[*i] >= '0') && (p[*i] <= '9')) {
        p_GIBuf[Bi] = p[*i];
        Bi++;
        *i++;
    }
    return StrToInt(p_GIBuf);
    free(p_GIBuf);
}
void GetStr(char *p, char *r, int *i) {
    //Getting string-data (train's name, particularly) from the string 
    int Bi = 0;
    while (((p[*i] >= 'A') && (p[*i] <= 'Z')) || ((p[*i] >= 'a') && (p[*i] <= 'z'))) {
        r[Bi] = p[*i];
        Bi++;
        *i++;
    }
}
//---------------------------------Structures------------------------------------
struct TIME {
    int hours;
    int mins;
};
struct TRAIN {
    int number;
    struct TIME time_arr; //arrival time
    struct TIME time_lea; //departure time
    char name[10];
};
int main() {
//-------------------------------data definition---------------------------------
    int i = 0;
    int *pi = &i;
    int buflen = 0;
    char *p_Buf = NULL;
    p_Buf = (char*)malloc(dim);
    struct TRAIN Arr_train[100];
//--------------------------------Files opening-----------------------------------
    FILE *fi;
    fi = fopen("1.txt", "r");
    if (fi == NULL) {
        printf("error of opening file \n");
    }
    else printf("DONE\n");
    //-----------------------------Data getting------------------------------------
    bool end = false;
    int n = 0;
    char *p_TrB = NULL; //for a train's name
    p_TrB = (char*)malloc(ldim);
    while (!end) {
        fgets(p_Buf, dim, stdin);
        //Getting Data in Arr_train[n]:
        Arr_train[n].number = GetInt(p_Buf, pi);
        *pi++; //go over '.'
        Arr_train[n].time_arr.hours = GetInt(p_Buf, pi);
        *pi++;
        Arr_train[n].time_arr.mins = GetInt(p_Buf, pi);
        *pi++;
        Arr_train[n].time_lea.hours = GetInt(p_Buf, pi);
        *pi++;
        Arr_train[n].time_lea.mins = GetInt(p_Buf, pi);
        GetStr(p_Buf, p_TrB, pi);
        n++;
        if (strlen(p_Buf) == 0) end = true;
    }
    free(p_TrB);
    free(p_Buf);
    scanf("%i", &i);
    return 0;
}
```

В блоке "Base function" написал функции:

> -int Power10(int x) - возведение целого числа 10 в степень x
>
> -int StrToInt(char *p) - перевод строки, состоящей из символов цифр, в целое число
>
> -int GetInt(char *p,int *i) - получение из строки p  целого числа с помощью
>   предыдущей функции StrToInt
>
> -void GetStr(char *p, char *r, int *i) - выделение строки символов r из строки большой строки p.
>   (p - строка данных из файла, например:">001.12:30.13:30.First;")

Вот файл данных:

> 001.12:30.13:30.First;
>   002.13:30.14:30.Second;
>   003.14:30.15:30.Third;
>   (номер_поезда.время_прибытия.время_отправления.название_станции)

**При запуске появляется сообщение об открытии файла, после чего выдает ошибку в функции GetInt (предпоследняя функция блока "Base functions") на строке** 
`while ((p[*i] >= '0') && (p[*i] <= '9')) {`

> Вызвано необработанное исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения. p
>   было 0xCEBF4F06.
>   [image: Ошибка]

По причине отсутствия опыта в работе с динамическим выделением памяти и структурами, не понимаю, откуда взялась ошибка. Буду крайне рад любой критике кода, указаниям на любые ошибки.

Comment: `int(p[i])`??? Вы что-то выдумываете. Этот код невозможно даже скомпилировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. В языке С постфиксные операторы всегда имеют более высокий приоритет, чем префиксные. Выражение

   ```
   *i++
   ```

   группируется как

   ```
   *(i++)
   ```

   то есть увеличивает значение указателя `i`, а не значение `*i`. То же самое относится и к вашим `*pi++`. Это, очевидно, совсем не то, что вы пытались сделать.
2. `int(p[i])` - что это за синтаксис такой? В языке С ничего подобного нет.
3. Использование `bool end = false;` требует включения `<stdbool.h>`. Где ваш `<stdbool.h>`?
4. `length = sizeof(p)-1` - что по-вашему тут вычисляется?
5. Чего вы пытались добиться этим

   ```
   return StrToInt(p_GIBuf); 
   free(p_GIBuf);
   ```

   Почему `free` стоит после `return`?